# ASP.net Membership Provider Website Administrator Tool

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I have created the necessary tables (aspnet_User,....) in Sql server Management Studio 2005 in my Database named "AuctionSite". So instead of making one in App_Data folder ,i 
want my website to point the database (AuctionSite) MembershipProvider, ProfileProvider,RoleProvider.

What is the way to achieve this or how to configure my website administrator to point that
Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set some properties in `web.config` to point to the database but couple of other things will also need modification.

```
<membership>
     <providers>
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,
                     System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
                     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
               connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
               applicationName="/"             
     </providers> 
</membership>
```

---

have a look at this tutorial

- [**Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server**](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-04-cs.aspx)